# Receive UDP broadcast datagram in C

Tags: sockets, network-programming, udp, broadcast

I have the following issue.

I need to send broadcast UDP datagram packet and a device that is connected to my local network should reply with another broadcast UDP datagram packet.
So the communication should be like this:

me -> 192.168.0.255 (or 255.255.255.255) : "Who is out there?"
my_device > 192.168.0.255: "It's me... IP:..."

Here a very important condition is that I should use always port 30303 as source and at the same time as a destination port. The devices on the other side can use a random port above 4000 for source port and 30303 port for the Destination port.

The problem is that with my code, I can send UDP broadcast, I can see with Wireshark, that the device answers my call, but I cant manage to make my program to receive the broadcast UDP packet.

here is my source:

`#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define DST_PORT    30303   
#define SRC_PORT    30303
#define BUFLEN 84
#define IP      "192.168.0.255"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct sockaddr_in addr, srcaddr;
    int fd;
    unsigned char buf[BUFLEN];
    unsigned char message[]={0x44, 0x69, 0x73, 0x63, 0x6f, 0x76, 0x65, 0x72, 0x79, 0x3a, 0x20, 0x57, 0x68, 0x6f, 0x20, 0x69, 0x73, 0x20, 0x6f, 0x75, 0x74, 0x20, 0x74, 0x68, 0x65, 0x72, 0x65, 0x3f, 0x00, 0x0a};
    int broadcast=1;
    if ((fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(IP);
    addr.sin_port = htons(DST_PORT);

    memset(&srcaddr, 0, sizeof(srcaddr));
    for(int i=0;i<BUFLEN;i++) buf[i]=0x00;
    for(int i=0;i<BUFLEN;i++) printf("0x%x", buf[i]);
    printf("\n\033[32mBUFFER CLEARED!\033[0m\n");
    srcaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    srcaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    srcaddr.sin_port = htons(SRC_PORT);

    setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, &broadcast, sizeof(broadcast));
    int slen = sizeof(addr);
    if (bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *) &srcaddr, sizeof(srcaddr)) < 0) {
        perror("bind");
        exit(1);
    }

  /* connect(fd, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(addr)); */


        if (sendto(fd, message, strlen(message)+2 , 0 , (struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(addr))==-1)
        {
           printf("\n\033[31mCouldnt send message!!!\033[0m\n");;
        }
        else printf("\n\033[32mDATAGRAM SENT!\033[0m\n");

    puts("\nI am waiting for DGRAM\n");
    slen=sizeof(rcvaddr);
     //close(fd);

    sleep(1);

    //connect(fd, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(addr));
    recvfrom(fd, buf, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &rcvaddr, &slen);
        printf("Recieved!\n");
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    char temp[4]="\0";
    for (int i=0; i<BUFLEN;i++)
    {
      printf("0x%x ", buf[i]);
    }


  return 0;
}`

What I'm trying to do is: 
 1. Create socket
 2. Change source port to a fixed port number
 3. Send UDP broadcast Datagram
 4. Receive UDP broadcast Datagram

Unfortunately, I receive the datagram I have to send instead of the one, that my device sends.

Comment: Does the peer send a response to 192.168.0.255 or 255.255.255.255? Is the interface settings correct? Paste `ip a` output at least for the interface with 192.168.0.x address.

Comment: @ZabojCampula
https://imgur.com/a/40Xpq <- this is what wireshark sniffed from a Windows tool communication with the same device. I want to make an alternative tool for Linux.
This is what wireshark sniffed with my tool, and what my tool shows me:
https://imgur.com/a/uYjWW

I mean the UDP Datagram is same, the device responds same to both tools, but my tool cant receive the device response package, while at same time I see with wireshark that it sends a response package. I tried to close wireshark and then trying using my tool, but results are the same.

Comment: Sorry, this:
https://imgur.com/a/Et4L2
 is what my windows tool shows. The problem is that even if I set 255.255.255.255  as destination IP, the devices responds to 192.168.0.255. I've tried both IP's as destination address, and with both the device responds, but I receive my own request packet.